# 2010 - Changing #VALUE! error in Calculated Column

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

I have a **calculated column** called **SUID #** that pulls the value from a **single line text input** called **SUID**. The formula in SUID # is:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)
```

If SUID is blank, the SUID # column will show #VALUE!

Is it possible to change that error text? I would like it to say "Please Enter the SUID Only on Package Pickup"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),"Please Enter the SUID Only on Package Pickup",RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: This is perfect. I was trying that ISERROR syntax earlier, but couldn't get it right. Thank you!

Comment: @nicolefdesigns kindly tick mark the answer to close the question :)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Since I'm a new user, I have a 5 minute wait time to be able to close the question. I think that is a bit ridiculous, but it can't be helped.

Comment: ^ Yes I observed that feature in the beginning.. I'm sure there will be strong reason for it.. Some new users usually leave the question open even when answered, and closing questions can only be done by questioner so thanks.. :)